# Reading columns in a csv file by indices

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to create a program in which reads a CSV file and writes in another file. My problem is, the file I'm ready is kinda big and I don't want to go through every column by doing this:

```
columns = defaultdict(list)
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)       
for row in reader:               
    for (k,v) in row.items(): 
          columns[k].append(v) 
print(columns['name'])
print(columns['id'])
...
```

I wanted to, instead, do `columns[0]` to find `'name'`, and so on. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are now reading the CSV with a `DictReader` this creates the columns based on names, in your case you could just use the [`reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```py
columns = defaultdict(list)
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)  
next(reader) # to skip the header row     
for row in reader:               
    for i, v in enumerate(row): 
          columns[i].append(v) 
print(columns[0])
print(columns[1])
```

Comment: When I try to run with reader it gives me an attribute error (i.e. `'_csv.reader' object has no attribute next()` or `'list' object has no attribute 'items'`); I'm, assuming it's because these attributes are for dictReader only.

Comment: I haven't actually tested it, but I think I fixed it now :-)
Correct, the `items()` function is used with dict type objects to loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question. If you are asking, "can I read only the first column?", then the short answer is no. CSV is specifically designed to read a fixed number of columns from variable length records. More specifically, the data is organized as a list of rows, not a list of columns. You can't just seek past what you don't want to read. It sounds like what you are trying to do is reorganized your data into columns.

If you want to minimize the processing of what you do read, it sounds like all you need to do is use `csv.reader` and skip the first row containing the header. Each row from the reader will return a list of strings and the construction of this list should be less expensive than a map.

If you collect the list of rows you can then put it in a [numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). A numpy array will allow you to access columns (e.g., `x[:, 0]`) or rows (e.g., `x[0, :]`).

Given that I am not entirely sure what you are asking, my answers may not not be what you are looking for; however, whatever your problem is, I am certain you cannot avoid reading the entire file.